# Configuring EclipseLink DDL Generation to ignore tables

Tags: oracle, eclipselink

I have several externally supplied tables which I can't modify.  In my case these are things like the built in Oracle tables.

What I have is several entities which map on to these tables, but when I do my DDL generation I don't want them to be generated.  Is there an annotation or an attribute I can set to ignore certain entities in the DDL generation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply switch to "create" ddl from "drop-create".  The "create" calls for the existing tables would be ignored.  Unfortunately there is currently no option in EclipseLink to prevent a table from being dropped when using "drop-create".  Your best option is to have EclipseLink write the DDL to file and remove the lines for tables you do not want altered.  It is likely that something similar will be available in a future version of EclipseLink.  You can monitor and provide feedback on the currently active "extensions" feature in EclipseLink : http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Development/2.4.0 . Monitor this page for more information.